# Can two different phone numbers be used to receive voice and text on one iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Can I have two different numbers asigned to the same iphone and receive text from both numbers on one device?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer appears to be **no** - regarding an [iOS 6](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/) device. It certainly **isn't** possible without [jailbreaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking). Also iPhone's [Phone.app](http://www.apple.com/iphone/built-in-apps/#phone) and Messages are clearly designed for a 1 phone number type setup.

However, there may be some "hacks" that may work well for you. If I were you, I would look into Google Voice. It certainly isn't ideal, but may be the best you can get. What you can do is have things forwarded to your regular phone number.

Check out http://www.google.com/voice/.

I believe you could work it so that you port one number into Google Voice, and then have your main/regular number on your iPhone in a standard way. When you get a call from your alternate phone number I believe it will forward it to your normal number and allow you to take the call normally. You can get the Google Voice app to text and call *from* your alternate phone number. The catch with that is that you will need data service - not just voice signal.

Comment: Before saying no or hacks, check the web please. And the Iphone 4 is equipped with dual sim (wonder why)! Since the @user45796 did not disclose what phone he/she has ....

Comment: @Borderline, there are a couple of important things here. 1st, dual sims require jailbreaking, and *very possibly won't work well on iOS 6* due to iMessages now being able to sync across devices. Also, the iPhone 4 *isn't* a dual-sim phone (despite there being a possibility you can get a special case and dual sim card to work with it). However, thank you for pointing that out, I will edit my answer to make sure it is accurate.

Comment: Google Voice probably won't work, unless you port all your numbers to it somehow. It can do one number -> rings multiple phones easily, but multiple numbers -> rings one phone is harder since they need to be in control of all the numbers, and idk if they let you port more than one.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is absolutely yes, assuming you are in the USA.

I do this myself using [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice). In fact, I don’t even know what my iPhone number is, I only give people my Google Voice number.

1. Select a new phone number from Google Voice
2. Enter your official iPhone number into your Google Voice account
3. Be sure to mark your official iPhone number as a “mobile” number which will allow you to receive text messages at that number.

Text messages sent to your Google Voice number can either be sent as text messages or as push notifications through the free [Google Voice app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-voice/id318698524?mt=8). I use push notifications and send/receive texts through that app.[1]

The only potential downside is that these text messages are not being sent through Apple’s iMessage system. But I have not found that to be a particularly important detail. In fact, I have setup iMessage to start messages using my email address, not my phone number, so people who send/receive iMessages from me never even see my official iPhone number. (People who do not use iMessage would, but in that case I choose to use the Google Voice app instead.)

Calls placed from your iPhone will show your official iPhone number in the caller-ID unless you use the Google Voice app, in which case your Google Voice number will appear.

The great thing about Google Voice is that you can filter incoming calls just like you filter your email. You can send some calls directly to voicemail. You can set it up so that calls from certain numbers get a “This number is not in service” message. You can set up different voicemail messages for different incoming phone numbers.

You can make it so that any call from someone not in your address book immediately goes to voicemail.

*Read that last part again.*

No more calls from telemarketers or people you don’t know.

You can also make it so that an unknown caller (someone with blocker caller ID and/or someone who is not in your address book) has to give their name before they will be connected. (Your phone will ring, a voice will tell you that you have a call from… and then you will hear their name, then you will either accept the call or send it to voicemail.)

**Google Voice is my favorite and most irreplaceable service from Google right now. My only fear is that someday they’ll shutter it because it doesn’t make them any money. But in the meantime, it’s a great service.**

---

  If you do not use the Google Voice app and opt instead to receive Google Voice text messages as direct text messages, I ***believe*** that you can reply to texts in the regular Messages.app and have them appear (to the recipient) as if they were from your Google Voice number, but I haven’t tried that so I can’t say for certain. I find push notifications preferable, and I send/receive texts through the Google Voice app so I am sure my caller ID info is correct in texts too.  ↩

Comment: There is also http://www.line2.com which is a service I have not used, but mention only as another option. I don't know if they do text messaging. Also, if you sign up for a trial account, I suggest using a disposable email account as they were quite persistent in trying to get me to sign up. (I created an account but never used it.) Eventually the "single serving" email address I had created for the trial started to get spam sent to it. So, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I do.
I switched from Telus to Virgin and the guy at Virgin set up my new iPhone with a temporary number. He then switched my original Telus number over to the new phone but now both numbers are connected to my phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number forwarded from one phone to an I phone you can uses that I phone to forwad to the third phone ! And the third phone will accept calls from both lines